# How to check thread / queue hierarchy in Swift / Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, swift

I have encountered a dead lock and want to see which tread / queue created which one? How is it possible? Unfortunately in `Debug navigator` it is not possible to order threads like this. Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print out thread address to terminal also, and you will able to couple with the address in `Debug navigator`. Then you will able to see which thread runned last, and cause deadlock.

`NSManagedObjectContext.description` includes this info too. But `NSThread` has similar property.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the left side the Threads.
Here you can go via click down to system call level.
It you have a real deadlock tow call must have the same memory address.
[image: Threads]

Answer (score 0):

Type `NSLog([NSThread callStackSymbols])` in the debug console.